# How to get a real number of Users from a Google Analytics report

Tags: excel, google-analytics

I pulled a month's worth of user numbers from Google Analytics. In GA, the report tells me I had 6.1M users in those 30 days. However, when doing a =SUM formula after exporting this to Excel, this number is 13.5M. I know that GA dedupes these user numbers by knowing that User A may come to your site 4 times in a month, so to not count that user 4 times. However, it appears that when exporting this report into Excel, these numbers are not deduped.

I want to know the % of my users who are doing something. However, I'm not sure how to calculate the numerator if the numbers in the Excel file are not accurate/are being counted more than once.

I have a screenshot of the Google Analytics report (did not include the numbers though, but just wanted to show where I'm talking about, so just picture 6.1M underneath the highlighted Users section).

In the Excel screenshot, my sample size is smaller (adds up to 2.0M), so therefore my Users number is smaller, but just to showcase what the Excel file looks like that I exported from GA.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the post and include a [mcve].  Without something we can pull down and test it is hard to give an answer to the problem

Comment: Updated with screenshots of GA and my Excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this number in Google Analytics Report, in the first row with weighted totals.

You cannot calculate it from the exported data because you lack the necessary information, the clientId.

Comment: Ok shoot, that's what I was worried about. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :) Mark answer as solved, pls